# Relationship with json-server

Tags: json, angular, json-server

I'm building a fake API with json-server and I came across a problem when passing a query. I can show the parameters of a relationship when I use `_expand`, but when it is a relationship within a child it does not work.

For example, I have this json that I access by passing`http://localhost:3000/schedules`:

```
{
   id: 1,
   date: "2020-04-25T14:20:00-03:00",
   status: "Novo serviço",
   usersId: 5,
   providersId: 1,
   servicesId: 1,
},
```

Now to show the relationship with the user I pass the following query:

```
http://localhost:3000/schedules?_expand=users
```

It returns as follows:

```
{
   id: 1,
   date: "2020-04-25T14:20:00-03:00",
   status: "Novo serviço",
   usersId: 5,
   providersId: 1,
   servicesId: 1,
   users: {
      id: 5,
      name: "Carla Pedroso",
      photo: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/01/19/17/48/woman-1149911_960_720.jpg",
      rating: 5,
      addressesId: 1,
   },
},
```

Well, my question is how I can show the JSON of the `addressesId`, because I already tried using`_expand` but without success.

Comment: I am afraid this website is predominant with mostly English speaking community.

Comment: I did the translation of the text, could you help me?

Comment: have you tried _embed ? https://github.com/typicode/json-server#relationships

Answer (score 3):

change the schedule property "usersId" to "userId",

should work with

> http://localhost:3000/schedules?_expand=user

and the response should be something like that:

```
{
  id: 1,
  date: "2020-04-25T14:20:00-03:00",
  status: "Novo serviço",
  providersId: 1,
  servicesId: 1,
  userId: 5,
  user: {
    id: 5,
    name: "Carla Pedroso",
    photo: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/01/19/17/48/woman-1149911_960_720.jpg",
    rating: 5,
    addressesId: 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With json-server you can add the parent and children of an element to the result, but it will only bring one level, so it will not bring grandparents or grandchildren's.

In your case instead of looking at the schedules you can look at the users and ask to expand the addresses and embed the schedules

```
http://localhost:3000/users?_expand=addresses&_embed=schedules
```